# About call bat file and get some information

Tags: batch-file

I want to ask about bat problem.

I write a file `HELLO.c` , which can call bat file start to get date and time(`aaa.bat`)

I get produced log to record informations.

**Problem **

I want to get file name who call the bat file `aaa.bat`, and `record.c` file name/information.

(get `HELLO.c` information)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1:

pass as an argument the file name of the caller.

HELLO.c side

```
system("aaa.bat HELLO.c");
```

aaa.bat side

```
@echo The call .c file is %1 >> C:\temp\%aaa%.log
```

Problem 2:

The call to create an executable file that counts up to create a file for counting. However Requires exclusive processing.